# How to change Firefox icon shown on panel and menus?

Tags: firefox, freedesktop, icons, cinnamon

I installed Firefox on Linux Mint Debian Edition with the Cinnamon desktop.

This Firefox package doesn't use the regular Firefox icon, with the fox curled around the world [image]; it has what I call the "orange eyeball" icon. [image]

Is there a way to have the standard Firefox icon show up on the panel ("taskbar") button and the menus?  This "eyeball" icon is so visually unappealing that if I can't change it, I'll uninstall Firefox and use Opera or Chrome instead.  (Yes, I really do find it that ugly.  I do not want to have to look at this thing.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer my own question:

Ignacio's answer takes care of the large icon on the system menu, and the taskbar launcher if you add one.  Changing the icon on the taskbar button/panel button took more digging.

Uninstalling the 'native' Firefox from LMDE (`sudo apt-get remove firefox`) and installing the tar.gz from http://getfirefox.com still left me with the orange eyeball on the panel button.

So I started hunting through folders, and eventually found it: The icon I can't stand is in `/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/16/firefox-png`.

I renamed the file to `firefox-ugly-icon.png`, and copied in the icon I want (from another system).  Problem solved.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that, if you don't replace the icon with another file, Firefox will just use the icon that came with it. That is what I wound up doing, so that I would get the current icon of Firefox and not the old one.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick and dirty workaround, you can download a build from upstream, the Mozilla Foundation, the only ones who are legally able to make builds of that web browser with the name "Firefox" and with the fox-and-globe logo.

But using the current version you have, maybe it is worth a shot trying [some instructions to replace the bundled icons](http://uselessdesires.deviantart.com/art/Change-the-Firefox-Window-Icon-90807695) (here, the icons are under `/usr/lib/firefox/chrome/icons/default/`).

Please note that [you are, officially, not allowed to distribute the result of said modification](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=50876) (this is also why many operating systems, such as Mint, won't carry builds with the official logo in their repositories, or will at least have a main build which does not have the official logo).

Answer (score 1):

I logged in with `gksudo` and drag the icon I wanted into `/usr/share/icons` and then doubled clicked on the taskbar icon and loaded the new one, simple. Probably should have put it in the `/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/16` but it worked so why fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the easy answer is staring you (or in this case 'me') right in the face. Took me forty-five minutes and some help from a fellow at the LinuxMint forum to figure something out what I should have known.

1. Right-click Menu button > Edit menu
2. In left pane, click Internet
3. In right pane, click *Firefox Web Browser* > click Properties
4. In the Launcher Properties box, click the Firefox icon on the left. then *Choose an icon* box opens
5. Navigate to where your new icon is located, click it, and click Open.
6. Close Launcher Properties box, then close Main Menu box.
7. Menu > Internet > right-click *Firefox Web Browser*
8. Click Add to panel

---

Now remove old icon in Menu panel, and in the Menu favorites list:

- Right-click your current Firefox Web Browser icon on the panel, click Remove.
- Click **Menu** > **Internet** > right-click **Firefox Web Browser**
- Click **Remove from Favorites**. Close Menu.

---

If steps 1-6 don't work you might need to create an entirely new menu item. Be sure to copy the command from the old menu item. It should be **firefox %u** unless yours is customized for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to copy the Firefox icons from another Linux computer and put them on the Linux Mint Maya computer.  In the example below, the dollar `$` prompt is the regular terminal prompt, and the pound `#` is the root user prompt.

CentOS 6.4 computer - connect a USB stick

Open terminal, switch to root, and locate icon files

```
# find / -name firefox.png -exec ls -ld {} \;
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 972 Jun 18 14:46 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/firefox.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1625 Jun 18 14:46 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/firefox.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1849 Jun 18 14:46 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/firefox.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2912 Jun 18 14:46 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/firefox.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5640 Jun 18 14:46 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/firefox.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 76949 Jun 18 14:46 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/firefox.png
```

Copy the above firefox.png files (16,22,24,32,48) to USB stick, 
renaming the new copies for the different sizes:

```
firefox16.png
firefox22.png
firefox24.png
firefox32.png
firefox48.png
```

Remove the USB stick.

On the Linux Mint Maya computer - connect USB stick.

Using File Browser, create an icons folder under `/tmp` called `Firefox_icons`.

Using File Browser, copy those five `firefoxNN.png` from USB stick to the icons folder.

Open terminal, and navigate to icons folder:

```
$ cd /tmp/Firefox_icons
```

Create a script called: `copy_icons.sh`

```
$ pluma copy_icons.sh
```

Paste these five lines:

```
cp firefox16.png /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/16/firefox.png
cp firefox22.png /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/22/firefox.png
cp firefox24.png /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/24/firefox.png
cp firefox32.png /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/32/firefox.png
cp firefox48.png /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/48/firefox.png
```

Save file and exit from Pluma.

Switch user to root, and navigate to icons folder:

```
$ su -
# cd /tmp/Firefox_icons
```

Make the script executable:

```
# chmod +x copy_icons.sh
```

Run script:

```
# ./copy_icons.sh
```

Reboot computer.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

To restore the official Firefox Icon on Linux Mint 19.03 cinnamon. You can copy the default icon theme, delete the alternative firefox icon, then use your newly created theme.

```
mkdir ~/.icons
cd ~/.icons
cp -R /usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/ .
mv Mint-Y/ Mint-Y-custom
cd Mint-Y-custom/
find -name "firefox*" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Then open the `Themes` application and select the `Mint-Y-custom` icon theme.