# Command to run executable with icon

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

(Ubuntu 18.04)
Is there a command to open an executable WITH a given icon? I'll give more background. I'm trying to create multiple google chrome "users" (NOT the "People" tab, I  need each user to have it's own set of people). I know you can do this, and I did, by first running

`mkdir ~/.config/google-chrome-Theo`

and

`mkdir ~/.config/google-chrome-Teddy`

Then making a Desktop executable that runs

`google-chrome --user-data-dir=$HOME/.config/google-chrome-Theo`

and another one that runs

`google-chrome --user-data-dir=$HOME/.config/google-chrome-Teddy`

That way, when I run the "Theo" executable, I get Theo's suite of People, bookmarks, etc. but when I run the "Teddy" executable, I get Teddy's People and bookmarks.
The issue with this is that I can change the icon of each of the Desktop executables, by going into their Properties menu, but I can't change the icon of the chrome instances that pop up. That is, when I open Theo and Teddy's chromes at once, there are two, generic chrome icons, and I have to search to find the one I want. Is there a command to open an executable WITH a given icon?

EDIT: I tried fra-san's answer, and it didn't seem to work for me. I'll clarify what I tried: I ended up with these two desktop files:

1. `Desktop/Chrome-Theo.desktop` with this content:

`#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Google Chrome
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --user-data-dir="/home/theo/.config/google-chrome-Theo" --class=theo
Icon=/home/theo/Icon-Blue.png
NoDisplay=true
StartupWMClass=theo`

2. `Desktop/chrome-teddy.desktop`, with this content:

`#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Google Chrome
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --user-data-dir="/home/ubuntu/.config/google-chrome-Teddy" --class=teddy
Icon=home/teddy/Icon-Red.png
NoDisplay=true
StartupWMClass=teddy`

However, when I open them, they still show the default chrome icon in the sidebar. Did I mess up somewhere?

EDIT 2:
I just realized that the two desktop executables are opening the same user of chrome... I bookmarked a page on the Theo chrome, and when I opened the Teddy one, it had that same bookmark. I'm really confused at this point.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! By "Desktop executables" are you meaning the `.desktop` files? They have an [`Icon` key](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys) that lets you set the "Icon to display in file manager, menus, etc ..."

Comment: Also, about your "there are two, generic chrome icons": where? Are you referring to the icons in the application top bar (as the [answer by sudodus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494284/315749) is showing)? Or to the icons in the taskbar at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @fra-san I mean the icons on the left of the screen.

Comment: Ok. I guess you are referring to the icons in the [dash](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html.en#activities) (I'm not on Ubuntu/GNOME). I suggest you to edit your question, adding this information and, for clarity, your Ubuntu version. (I can think of at least three or four different places where an application icon is shown, and most of them have their specific settings). This will help others to help you.

Comment: On Edit 2: are you sure you did not sign in to the same Google account on both your Chrome profiles? Maybe your bookmarks are being synchronized. You should probably make your tests with two new, empty user data directories, without copying/moving existing profiles.

Comment: @fra-san I just made 2 completely new directoried from the terminal- Theo1 and Teddy1. When I opened Teddy1, it had all my profiles that were on the default user, and for some reason when I opened Theo I got an error even though all the code is the same except for the icon and "class" things. And, once again, they keep the same icon.

Comment: After creating two empty directories (to be used as Chrome's user data directories), did you also accordingly change the value of `--user-data-dir` in the two `.desktop` files? I would suggest you to create a new operating system user, create two directories in its profile, create two `.desktop` files, edit their `--user-data-dir` options, start Chrome by those `.desktop` files. Note that, when doing these tests, you should have no other Chrome instances open, as they may lead to confusing results.

Answer (score 1):

#### Assumptions

I will assume that: you are on Ubuntu 18, your desktop environment is GNOME 3, you are using `google-chrome-stable`.
Also, I will assume that the icons you are referring to are those in [GNOME's dash](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html.en#activities) (actually, it is Ubuntu Dock, which as far as I can tell is a fork of dash, but I'm currently unable to link to any meaningful documentation). Its default behavior is to group together multiple instances of Chrome. Thus, finally I'm assuming that you want distinct icons for distinct *Chrome profiles* in Dock.

#### Solution

Basically, the steps you need to reproduce are explained in my answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484798/315749). That won't be enough, though, presumably because of [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118613) - which makes Google Chrome ignore the `--class` option unless the `--user-data-dir` option is also specified (and distinct directories are used).

You will need two things:

1. Some edits to your desktop files;
2. Two distinct Chrome user data directories.

Point 2: fortunately you already have them: `~/.config/google-chrome-Theo` and `~/.config/google-chrome-Teddy`.

Point 1: I don't have enough details about your desktop files, so here I'm creating them from scratch.
By default, the location of per-user desktop files is `~/.local/share/applications`.
Thus, I create:

1. `~/.local/share/applications/chrome-theo.desktop`, with this content:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Name=Google Chrome
   Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --user-data-dir="/home/your_user/.config/google-chrome-Theo" --class=theo
   Icon=icon_for_theo
   NoDisplay=true
   StartupWMClass=theo
   ```
2. `~/.local/share/applications/chrome-teddy.desktop`, with this content:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Name=Google Chrome
   Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --user-data-dir="/home/ubuntu/.config/google-chrome-Teddy" --class=teddy
   Icon=icon_for_teddy
   NoDisplay=true
   StartupWMClass=teddy
   ```

Replace `your_user` in the paths with your actual username.
Replace `icon_for_theo` and `icon_for_theddy` with:

- The *full path* to the icon files you are going to use; OR
- The *name*, without extension, of the icon files if you are making them available system-wide in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/`.

The second option is much more complex to set up, but it allows you to have variously sized icons. Refer to [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/722182/882661) for further information - it ultimately links to the [Icon Theme Specification](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/icon-theme-spec/) by freedesktop.org.

How does it work:

- The `--class=` option gives two distinct `WMCLASS`es to the two Chrome instances, making them non-groupable in Dock;
- The `StartupWMClass=` sets a link between the open Chrome windows and the desktop entries that launched them, letting them keep their custom icons in Dock;
- Due to the bug mentioned above, the `--user-data-dir=` option *and the two distinct* user data directories are needed for the first two points to be effective.

#### Notes and troubleshooting

Tested with: live Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Xorg session, `google-chrome-stable` 71.0.3578.98-1.

Borrowing from the comments to my [aforementioned answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/485387/315749):

- It is advisable to test this kind of configurations on a clean system: at least, new Chrome profiles and user data directories; at best, a dedicated user (possibly created solely for testing purposes).
- `xprop` can be used for checking if the `--class` option is being honoured:

  ```
  ## This example uses chromium instead of Google Chrome!
  ## With default settings:
  $ xprop WM_CLASS
  WM_CLASS(STRING) = "chromium", "Chromium"

  ## With --class=test_class
  $ xprop WM_CLASS
  WM_CLASS(STRING) = "chromium", "test_class"
  ```

Comment: This didn't work for me, I still got the default chrome icons. (I updated my question to reflect what I tried).